# Returning a Function - Nothing logging to the console

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, higher-order-functions

I am having trouble seeing where I have gone wrong in writing this 'transformArray' function. I am trying to make it take in a function as an argument, apply it to each element of some array. Why does it not return anything?

```
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
function transformArray (aFunction) {
    return function (array) {
        return array.forEach(aFunction);
    };
}
var halve = transformArray(function (num) {return num/2;});
console.log(halve(array1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `Array.forEach` is an iterator. It always returns `undefined`.

> [**MDN:**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) `forEach()` executes the callback function once for each array element;
>   unlike `every()` and `some()` it, **always returns the value undefined**.

What you need is `Array.map`

> The `map()` method creates **a new array** with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.

```
function transformArray (aFunction) {
    return function(array) {
        return array.map(aFunction);
    };
}
```

(Emphasis mine)

Comment: Thank you ! It works perfectly  now. I forgot foreach doesn't return anything

Comment: @JessicaO'Brien glad to have helped :)